# How to look for a string in a filename and send that file via email?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that contains several PDF files.  They have a unique identifier within the filename that is two characters.  Example:  XYZ_A1_123.pdf, XYZ_QQ_456.pdf, etc.  A1 and QQ are the identifiers.

The identifiers match specific email addresses.  I have a CSV file that has two columns, the ID and the matching email address.  I can't get my script to look for that specific identifier and send the file.  If the PDF file has only the identifier in the name, such as "A1.pdf", the script works fine.  Here's my code so far.  Also, I'm looking to add a progress bar but not sure how.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
$csv = Import-Csv "," -path C:\Test\emails.csv -header "id","email"

foreach ($item in $csv) {
$filename = "$($item.id).pdf"
}

$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "587"
$emailSmtpUser = "email@address.com"
$emailSmtpPass = "mypassword"

$emailFrom = "me@address.com"
$emailTo = $item.email

$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage( $emailFrom , $emailTo )
$emailMessage.Subject = "This is the subject" 
#$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true #true or false depends
$emailMessage.Body = "This is the body."
$emailMessage.Attachment = $filename
$emailMessage.Attachments.add($filename)

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , 
$emailSmtpServerPort )
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $True
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( 
$emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );
$SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
```

Comment: "Here is a pile of code that doesn't work and I want this and this and that!" --> https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  --> start with PS ISE debugger step through, and see what the first four lines of your code are doing.

Comment: You can simplify your code significantly by using the `send-mailmessage` command and using the `-attachments` parameter. [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1) it's powershell 3.0 - 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a test file to mimic the file you described with codes and e-mail addresses:

```
echo "AF,a@p.com" > test.csv
echo "QC,q@p.com" >> test.csv
cat .\test.csv
```

The following snippet will pull the file's code, compare it to the address list, and retrieve the e-mail address if present:

```
$addresses = Import-Csv -Path .\test.csv -Header code, address
$files = ls .\*.pdf

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $file_code = $file.name.Split('_')[1]
    $addresses | where { $_.code -eq $file_code } | select address
    # ...send email...
}
```

Looks like you've got the e-mail stuff on-lock so I won't rehash that here. I'd only do the e-mail stuff if you find a matching address.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It makes sense but my emails aren't sending now even with matching addresses.  I think it's due to the following lines, as I don't know how to reference them using your code:
...
    $emailTo = $item.email
    $emailMessage.Attachments.add($filename)

Comment: That's a different question :-) And, for you comment. Try using "Send-MailMessage". It's better documented.